# How to display all data based on current user logged in

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

userSection.php

```
<?php  
require_once '../include/DbOperations.php';

$response = array(); 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    $uname = trim($_GET['username']);
    if(isset($uname)){
       $db = new DbOperations(); 

    if($db->studentLogin($uname)){
        $sections = $db->studentSection($uname);
        $response['error'] = false;         
        $response['id'] = $sections['id'];
        $response['lastname'] = $sections['lastname'];
        $response['section'] = $sections['section'];
        $response['year_level'] = $sections['year_level'];
        $response['school_year'] = $sections['school_year'];

    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "No Data";          
    }

}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
}
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

sectionList.class

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Constants.USER_GRADE,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                  //it should display the data of current user id
                  //On this part it doesn't display anything.
                  //example `id`=`1`. it should display all `id` equals to `1`

                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                            if(sectionList!=null) {
                                sectionList.clear();
                            }
                                //traversing through all the object
                                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject sections = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                if (!sections.getBoolean("error")) {
                                        //adding the product to product list
                                        sectionList.add(new ListGradeData(
                                                sections.getInt("id"),
                                                sections.getString("section"),
                                                sections.getString("level"),
                                                sections.getString("schoolyear")
                                        ));
                                }
                            }

                        //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                        LatestGradeAdapter adapter = new LatestGradeAdapter(getActivity(), sectionList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //adding our stringrequest to queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).add(stringRequest);
```

How to display all data that `id` = `1`.
My current username `id` is `1`. but it doesn't display anything its blank every time i run the application.
I tried to put this also,

```
{
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", username);
                return params;
            }

        };
```

but still it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The **GET** request parameters in volley are passed as part of the **url**, so change the url to

```
String url = "http://youraddress.com/userSection.php?username=" + username;
```

Passing parameters via `getParams()` method is done in **POST** requests.

Comment: thanks sir.
I have still error. it doesn't display the data.

Comment: I'll put a comment.

Comment: The response is not a ``JSONArray`` but a normal ``JSONObject ``. To make sure, try the url with parameter in your browser and you'll find the result a normal json.